# Angular 4 app, Authorization has been denied for this request

Tags: angular, typescript, http

Hello I am getting this message when I am making a post request, but not a get request.

> Authorization has been denied for this request.

I want to say that this works with the WPF APP that is connected to it, and it works with Postman. So that leads me to believe that it is my typescript call.

```
post(url: string, body:any): Observable<any> {

    let options = this.getOptions(body);

    this.addJsonToHeaders(options.headers);

    return this.http.post(this.appConfig.baseRoute + url, options);
}

private getOptions(body?:any): RequestOptions {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization', `${this.sessionService.session.token_type} ${this.sessionService.session.access_token}`);

    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    if (body !== undefined) {
        options.body = body;
    }

    return options;
}

private addJsonToHeaders(headers: Headers): void {
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
}
```

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong with my request?

Just for your info I am using Owin with Web Api

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so after fighting with this for about 2 hours I have found the issue. I thought that I would post here and hope to help the next person.

The issue was, the way that I was adding the body, you cant add the body under the options. so I have to change to this:

```
post(url: string, body:any): Observable<any> {

    let options = this.getOptions(body);

    this.addJsonToHeaders(options.headers);

    return this.http.post(this.appConfig.baseRoute + url, body, options);
}

private getOptions(body?:any): RequestOptions {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization', `${this.sessionService.session.token_type} ${this.sessionService.session.access_token}`);

    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return options;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have passed Options in the second parameter of the POST request. Ideally it should be the body.

If you do not have anything to post then send it as blank

```
let body = '';
return this.http.post(this.appConfig.baseRoute + url, body, options);
```